# Replacing null values with 0 in visual basic and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, aggregate-functions, isnull, dbnull

I am getting an error that states:

> "Operator '+' is not defined for type 'Integer' and type 'DBNull'."

While highlighting this:

> TotalBoxes += TotalBoxescmd.ExecuteScalar

I thought I was converting the DBNull Value into a zero with the way my sql command is set up. This is what I have, am I not correctly formatting the dbnull value into a zero?

```
 For Each item As Object In chkLstShipments.CheckedItems
            Dim checkedItem As Integer
            checkedItem = Val(item)



            Dim TotalBoxescmd As New SqlCommand("Select sum(isnull(LineBoxes, 0)) FROM ShipmentLineTable Where ShipmentNumber = @ShipmentNumber", con)
            TotalBoxescmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipmentNumber", checkedItem)

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

                            TotalBoxes += TotalBoxescmd.ExecuteScalar
            con.Close()
        Next
```

Comment: Move the IsNull outside the sum, `ISNULL(SUM(LineBoxes), 0)`

Comment: I can see how that can be a possibility but the way I set the code up in my project, there has to be a shipmentnumber, I made an edit to show that the user checks shipment numbers in a checklistbox. the checklistbox grabs existing shipment numbers from the table. My error must be what kblok stated, that I needed to move my ISNULL outside the sum.

Comment: if no record is found with ShipmentNumber = @Shipmentnumber than the result will be NULL. Why ? because it returned no records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `TotalBoxes` declaration to make sure it is correctly initialized
(at `0` for example or from a previous lifetime).

By the way, **you need to move the `ISNULL` function outside the `SUM`** in case no lines return for the given `ShipmentNumber`. You don't need `ISNULL` inside the `SUM` because `SUM` function handles properly `NULL` values.

```
ISNULL(SUM(LineBoxes), 0)
```

Also if the `ShipmentNumber` **MUST be valid**, check the real value of the parameter in debug mode, the value recovery mechanism might be wrong.

## Examples

Here examples of how SUM is handled with and without the ISNULL,
with or without lines.

For the following data :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [myColumn] FROM [myTable]

myColumn
---------------
NULL
3         
5
```

### Without ISNULL

#### Without lines

```
SELECT SUM([myColumn]) as [SumWithoutIsNull]
  FROM [myTable]
  WHERE 0=1

SumWithoutIsNull
---------------------------------------
NULL
```

#### With lines

```
SELECT SUM([myColumn]) as [SumWithoutIsNull]
  FROM [myTable]

SumWithoutIsNull
---------------------------------------
8
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

### With IsNull

#### Without lines

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM([myColumn]), 0) as [SumWithIsNull]
  FROM [myTable]
  WHERE 0=1

SumWithIsNull
---------------------------------------
0
```

#### With Lines

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM([myColumn]), 0) as [SumWithIsNull]
  FROM [myTable]

SumWithIsNull
---------------------------------------
8
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Answer (score 2):

use for code sql

```
ISNULL(SUM(LineBoxes), 0)
```

Or

In your code VB

```
 TotalBoxes += TotalBoxescmd.ExecuteScalar
 if TotalBoxes is nothing then
 TotalBoxes = 0
 end if
```